# Deriving an ordered sequence from 5 scrambled ones

Tags: c++, algorithm, computer-science

I've been assigned to do a problem that goes something like this:

My program should derive a list of integers A[1...N], where A[j] represents the jth integer in the list.

To derive it, my program will be inputted 5 lists, each of N integers (the same exact ones as in A[1...N], although scrambled). Each of these lists will be generated this way:

The list is put into order, just like A[1...N]. The list is then scrambled, which is done by removing at least 0 integers from this list, and placing them BACK into any position in the said list. In each of the 5 lists, each number is moved at most one time (although a number could end up at a different index as a result of other numbers shifting around).

**FOR EXAMPLE**

Assume N is 5, and the correct sequence A is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

The program would be entered these 5 sequences:

```
1,2,3,4,5

2,1,3,4,5

3,1,2,4,5

4,1,2,3,5

5,1,2,3,4
```

How would it be able to determine that the target/original sequence was {1,2,3,4,5}?

Could anyone point me in the right direction? (This *is* a homework problem)

Tell me if you need me to clarify the problem more.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem as stated is nonsensical (who uses phrases like "removing at least 0 elements"?)  And unsolvable.  If you have a list of N numbers and are able to take any N of them out and scramble them up into new positions, five results of this scrambling operation won't be enough information to tell you what the input list was.  Because those could be any five lists with the original numbers.  You need some other constraints you're not mentioning.

Comment: He states that each position can only be scrambled once

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of size N and use it as an index for the other arrays. For instance, if you created an integer array index[N], you could manipulate it and use its values as indices for the other arrays, i.e. array1[index[N]]. Depending on how you manipulated this index array, you could use it for either scrambling or sorting.

Comment: I've given an example problem/input in the question. Maybe that will help clarify it.